# Is there a way to assign the Class in Java at Runtime?

Tags: java, class, dynamic, reflection

Since I am refactoring my code right now, I am trying to first sort out possible code duplicates.
As a posible duplicate I see the 2 methods which basically read files: One from FTP and another from local filestructures. The problem is, that they of course use different classes to achieve the same things. The variable directoryListing is the tricky one.

```
readLogs(boolean useFTP){
// directory Listing of course needs to be of a different type here or not being declared at all 
    File[] directoryListing;
    File dir = Settings.getInputfolder();
    if(useFTP){
            // ftp implementation
            client = new FTPClient();               
            client.connect(Settings.getFtpHost());
            client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            client.login(Settings.getFtpLoginname(), Settings.getFtpPassword());
            client.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

            //directoryListing should be of type FTPFile[] here
            directoryListing = client.listFiles(Settings.getInputfolder().toString());
    else{
        //directoryListing should be of type File[] in this case
        directoryListing = dir.listFiles();
    }
    if (directoryListing == null) {
            log.error("Input-folder not found:" + dir.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    //I want to be able to iterate - here myFolder might be of type File oder FTPFile
    for (Object myFolder : directoryListing) {
    ...
    ...
    }
}
```

The only methods I am using later on in the code have the exact same signatures on both File and FTPFile:
    getName()
    isFile()
    isDirectory()
    listFiles()
I have used reflections for those e.g.

```
Method getFolderNameMethod = myFolder.getClass().getMethod("getName");
String name = (String) getFolderNameMethod.invoke(myFolder);
```

In what way can I achieve a somewhat dynamic declaration of the directoryListing variable?

Thank you very much for your time and advice in advance! :D

Comment: Is it possible to use Generics here? I mean create a class which iterates over the list and does the processing but it is a generic class, now you certainly know that when useFTP is true it is fetching the type of FTPFile instance and in other case it is fetching the File instance this might simplify the processing.

Comment: @BilboBaggins As far as I know, you cannot iterate over the list without knowing the Type of the List(FTPFile[] or File[]) so I would fail before I could fetch. A good idea though...

Comment: thanks :) I was also thinking about strategy pattern to get the list of Directory, i.e. if the "useFTP" true then invoke an instance of a class where you have implemented the FTPFile related stuff else invoke and use another instance for File :)

Comment: @BilboBaggins Well doing it this way will sill produce a lot of duplicate code for the 2 cases FTP and local :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Strategy and Adapter pattern:

First define the common interface

```
interface VirtualFile {
  /*
  getName()
  isFile()
  isDirectory()
  listFiles()
  */
}
```

then create two adapter (one for File, one for FTPFile)

```
class FileAdapter implements VirtualFile {
  // delegates every method to the wrapped file
}

class FTPFileAdapter implements VirtualFile {
  // delegates every method to the wrapped ftp file
}
```

Then refactor `readLogs`:

```
readLogs(FileStrategy fileOrFtp){
  List<VirtualFile> directoryListing = fileOrFtp.listDirectory();
  for (VirtualFile myFolder : directoryListing) {
    ...
    ...
  }
}

interface FileStrategy {
  List<VirtualFile> listDirectory();
}

class FTPFileStrategy implements FileStrategy {
   // implement useFTP case (settings should be passed to the constructor
   // wrap each resulting FTPFile into a FTPFileAdapter
}

class LocalFileStrategy implements FileStrategy {
   // implement !useFTP case (settings, e.g. root folder should be passed to the constructor
   // wrap each resulting File into a FileAdapter
}
```

This keeps all concerns separated and additionally:
- no ifs any more
- no casting
- no reflection
- shorter methods/classes

Answer (score 1):

I have used apache-commons-vfs in the past:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/

If you don't want to ad a lib, you could create an interface and 2 implementations of it, but VFS will give you more supported filesystems and probably be easier to maintain in the long run.

I'm sure there are others, but I've never needed anything other than the apache one so I can't speak to them.

Edit:

Based on your comment, I'd crate a factory, something like:

```
public class FSFactory{
  public static IFSInteface getInterfaceFor(FSType t){
     if(FSType.FTP.equals(t)){
        return new FtpFileGetter();
     } else if (FSType.LOCAL.equals(t)){
        return new FSFileGetter();
     }
  }
}
```

The code is not tested, but this is how I handle stuff like this.

Comment: Well yes I do have 2 implementations of the code right now anyway. What I really want to do is to determine "on runtime" whether directoryListing should be of Type FTPFile[] or File[] thus reducing duplicate code in the long run. Thank you for the library tip though. I will try it out in the next project :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Could you elaborate a little more on how I could use the Factory to set the directoryListing Class? e.g. how I should call it from my code? Or what to do with the IFSInterface once I have it?

Comment: I'd factor each branch of the `if` into separate classes with a `listFiles()` method and use the factory to get an instance instead of the if/else in your code.